# Can't update domain.address

Tags: civimail

After upgrading to 4.6.0 I can no longer update the value of the domain.address token. I try to update the address in Administer > Organization Address and Contact, but after saving the new address it reverts to the old address.

Comment: Did you go through the standard [troubleshooting steps](http://civicrm.org/bug-reporting) prior to posting this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you replicate on d46.demo.civicrm.org and then file a bug report at issues.civicrm.org? Thanks.

Comment: no. not a developer. just an end user that was directed here from the old forums.

Comment: Are there any problems on site, or just this page? You could try following steps 9 and 13-16 at   http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location. If that's not working go to Administer > System Settings > Debugging and error handling, turn on debugging, try doing the edit again, then if it doesn't work check the timestamps on the last message or two in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.(gobbledegook).log are from you attempt and if so edit your question to provide them.